# C++ EnumDisplayMonitors from HDC

Tags: c++, msdn, gdi, monitors

Why does DisplayMonitors fail when from HDC?

```
HDC monitorDC = (CreateDC(displayDevices[0].DeviceName, displayDevices[0].DeviceName, NULL, NULL));
// Generates valid HDC from EnumDisplayDevices
EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, 0)
// Returns true
EnumDisplayMonitors(monitorDC, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, 0)
// Returns false
```

[EnumDisplayMonitors MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd162610(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Are you sure, that moditorDC is valid? Try to pass any DC got from window.

Comment: Can you paste a small reproducible example?

Comment: First argument to CreateDC is driver but you pass device name there.

Comment: The DC is valid and will return things such as GetPixel for specified monitor.

@Tomashu CreateDC states that 'lpszDriver' and 'lpszDevice' **"If lpszDriver is DISPLAY or the device name of a specific display device, then lpszDevice must be NULL or that same device name"**

Comment: MSDN also says this about lpszDevice: "To obtain valid names for displays, call EnumDisplayDevices". It clearly should be possible to do this.